# Missing Settings in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME 3.28.2

Tags: gnome, settings, gnome-control-center

I found that in my system, some settings items are missing, for example are missing 'users', 'online accounts' and others setups.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with GNOME 3.28.2.

I'm able to see full setups using terminal command :

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

with root privileges (with `sudo`).

I tried to reinstall `gnome-control-center`, `gnome-desktop`
or to put in the `.desktop` file the exec command `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center`. 
I tried also to reset GNOME Tweaks and GNOME settings (with command `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`).

But the result remains the same.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

If you reinstalled linux manteining old home, than look in your home at the path:
/home/marco/.local/share/applications
there are lot of file with extension '.desktop'
Delete entire folder or, if you prefer, eliminate only files with name like 'gnome-...-panel.desktop'.

The same files were a old copy of original that are located into 
usr/share/applications